# Restart node.js app in detatched screen after server reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, display

Actually I start my node.js app with a shell file named run.sh:

```
while true; do
    node index.js
done
```

I start it with screen and then detatch the screen so that I can log out from ssh:

```
screen -L -S myapp bash run.sh
```

I want to harden it against server reboot. I tried to use a cronjob with the screen command but get the error that it has to run from a screen. I want to have the screen so I can log back in with ssh and open it when I need to. Is there a way to achieve this somehow?

Comment: Check the `-m` and `-d` options for `screen`

Comment: I tried in my cron ```screen -L -S -d myapp /home/app/run.sh``` but it still says: Must be connected to a terminal. I also tried -D -RR but still same error.
Btw I set up the cron from my plesk panel.

Comment: Problem solved:
```/usr/bin/screen -dmSL myapp bash /home/app/run.sh```